# Error: Activity resulted into multiple skype activities while sending an activity with text and attachment to teams channel

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am sending an activity which has text and attachments using `TeamsInfo.sendMessageToTeamsChannel` method in teams channel. I am getting `Activity resulted into multiple skype activities` error. It works fine if I sent only attachment. Below is code sample.

```
 let activity = { type: ActivityTypes.Message };
 activity.text = displaymessage;
 activity.attachments = [attachments];

await this.adapter.createConversationAsync(MICROSOFT_APP_ID, channelId, process.env.MICROSOFT_SERVICE_URL, 'https://api.botframework.com', conversationParameters, async (context) => {
                const teamsChannelId = teamsGetChannelId(context.activity) || channelId;
                await TeamsInfo.sendMessageToTeamsChannel(context, activity, teamsChannelId, MICROSOFT_APP_ID);
            });
```

Comment: The code is trying to update a message (1 card) to something that's going to become 2 messages (text + card). That's why it's giving the error "Activity resulted into multiple skype activities".

Comment: Could you please have look into this sample-https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/bot-type-ahead-search-adaptive-cards/nodejs/bots/teamsBot.js#L24